# Is there a way that I can see what direction surrounding wifi networks are coming from?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have been messing around with inSSIDer 3 and it allows me to see the strength of surrounding wifi networks, but I was wondering if there is a program that allows me to the the actual directions the signals are coming from.

Comment: I assume you would at least need a directional antenna.  Most WiFi units have an omni-directional antenna, e.g. a monopole.

Comment: You could build a [cantenna](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-a-wifi-antenna-out-of-a-pringles-can-nb/) move it around and monitor the strengh of one particular signal.

Comment: D'oh. I do indeed have an omni-directional antenna. It seems there is an additional DIY project on my list now!

Answer (score 1):

Product suggestions are off topic and so this will likely be closed.  However, we have used [Heatmapper](http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/ekahau-heatmapper) to do what you want.  You have to do some walking around to determine approximate direction of APs.  Worked well for us to find a rogue AP